# enable php_interbase.dll extension with htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, hosting, interbase

I'm using [hostinger.es](https://www.hostinger.es/) as my host, I can't access the `php.ini` file I get forbidden error message.

is it possible to change `php.ini` with a `.htaccess` file and enable `php_interbase.dll` with this?

Thanks.

Comment: you should try to use `dl` function [Check Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dl.php). But again it won't easy on a hosting service. as giving permission to load a dll can create serious security issues. Your best bet is ask the service provider to enable the extension, if they refuse, try another provider.

Comment: Hello Bansi!

dl function is forbidden in hostinger.... i have to change provider.... 

Thanks!